# create an array in javascript using the C# arrays in Asp

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, webforms

I am trying to access an array that is initialized in C# code behind in the aspx file using JavaScript. My array looks like the following:

```
arr[0]="IE 7.0,IE 8.0";
arr[1]="chrome 23.0";
```

I want to access this array in javascript and then convert each one i.e `arr[0]` into a new array using:

```
var Browsers=new Array();
Browsers=arr[0].split(',');
```

Can any one help me in doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a scriptmanager to push the content to the front?

Comment: an alternative is you can also include a JS file in aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below it will help you...

**Code behind :**
Declare a Public Variable in code-Behind like below...

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string[]  arr ={"IE 7.0,IE 8.0","chrome 23.0"};
```

**Javascript :**

```
 <script>
    var IEarray = '<%=arr[0] %>'.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < IEarray.length; i++)
        alert(IEarray[i]);

    var Chromearray = '<%=arr[1] %>'.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < Chromearray.length; i++)
        alert(Chromearray[i]);           
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to get json string from your array;

```
string serial = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(arr);
```

then use any prefered technique to render this string into client;
for example insert it right in aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myclientarr = JSON.parse('<%= serial %>');
</script>
```

Other options is to use scriptmanager or to create ashx which will return your data, then refer it in page.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your C# array to JavaScript format and assign the value on the page.

```
// C#
var arr = new string[]{ "IE 7.0,IE 8.0", "chrome 23.0" };
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsArray =
    arr.Select(s => s.Split(','))
       .Select(serializer.Serialize);

<!-- JS -->
<script>
    var browsers = <%= jsArray[0] %>;

</script>
```